# Why not a 32 bit architecture use two registers to store the address which will be equal to 64 bit and can use larger space of ram

Tags: ram, processor

I was just digging into 32 bit and 64 bit processors and found a satisfactory answer saying a 32 bit machine can only store a max number of 2^32 in one of its register so at max it can utilize only around 4gb as it can only track a max of as many integers.

But i was wondering why not use two registers to store address similar to how it use two register when storing a very large number as 1000000000000.

Comment: There are machines that do this. Its just very slow

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a datatype like LONG. This will just spill over onto another register. The only difference is that accessing speed and the operations you do with these values are not standard and will require significantly more computation time than on a 64-bit machine.

Consider the addition of 2 LONG in a 32-bit machine. Then the ALU is only suited for 32-bit values thus it will have to do them separately, that makes a lot of unneeded fetch and stores.